# Save data in a temporary .csv file to another csv file

Tags: c#, csv, savefiledialog

I have a problem. I have created a temporary .csv file, which contains a lot of data. The directory is a string: `path = @"C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\TempFile.csv";`.
I want to save this temporary file as a .csv file, when the user click on the save button. I have created a dialog, so the user is able to choose where to save the file.

```
private void SaveBT_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();

            saveDialog.Filter = "CSV File|*.csv";
            saveDialog.Title = "Gem en CSV fil";

            if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: so what's the problem here?

Comment: I'm confused about how to save the data from that temporary file to the new file.

Comment: Take a look at [File.Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

erm, how about?

```
File.Copy(tempFileName, saveFialog.FileName);
```